# Re-enabling a button after disabling it in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some poorly written if statements I'd like some help with.

I am attempting to cycle through divs using left and right arrow buttons.

When I use the right arrow and reach the last div (called using the class selector "pars"), I disable the right arrow to show there is no more content. Likewise, when using the left arrow and the first div is reached, I disable the left arrow.

How do I adjust the code to allow the buttons to be re-enabled when the first and last divs respectively, are not visible?

**HTML**

```
<div class="pars active cont-3"><p>Content-1</p></div>
<div class="pars cont-3"><p>Content-2</p></div>
<div class="pars cont-3">Content-3</p></div>
<div id="btn-cycle"> 
<button id="cycle-back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-3x fa-angle-left</i></button>
<button id="cycle-forward"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-3x fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pars.active {
display: block;
}

#btn-cycle {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:right;
    width:25%;
    color:#565655;
    padding:0.5em;
}

.cont-3 {
    padding:1em;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    font-size:0.7em;
    line-height:1.35em;
    font-family:"raleway", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $pars = $('.pars');
var $fwdBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-forward');
var $backBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-back');

$('#cycle-forward').click(function() {
    var $next = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.pars');
    if (!$next.length) $next = $pars.first();
    $next.addClass('active');
    if ($pars.last().is(':visible')) {
        $fwdBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        $fwdBtn.disabled = false;
    }
});

$('#cycle-back').click(function() {
    var $prev = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').prev('.pars');
    if (!$prev.length) $prev = $pars.last();
    $prev.addClass('active');
    if ($pars.first().is(':visible')) {
        $backBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        $backBtn.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Cheers!

Comment: use length and index

Comment: Do the visible check to enable/disable buttons for both buttons in both click handlers. Also you could do each check in one line: `backBtn.disabled = $pars.first().is(':visible');`

Comment: If the the arrows are clicked, enable left and right...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use the last if statements I added to both functions.

```
var $pars = $('.pars');
var $fwdBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-forward');
var $backBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-back');

$('#cycle-forward').click(function() {
    var $next = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.pars');
    if (!$next.length) $next = $pars.first();
    $next.addClass('active');
    if ($pars.last().is(':visible')) {
        $fwdBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        $fwdBtn.disabled = false;
    }
    if (!$pars.first().is(':visible')) {
        $backBtn.disabled = false;
    }

});

$('#cycle-back').click(function() {
    var $prev = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').prev('.pars');
    if (!$prev.length) $prev = $pars.last();
    $prev.addClass('active');
    if ($pars.first().is(':visible')) {
        $backBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        $backBtn.disabled = false;
    }
    if (!$pars.last().is(':visible')) {
        $fwdBtn.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your JS hope it could work for you

```
var $pars = $('.pars');
        var $fwdBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-forward');
        var $backBtn = document.getElementById('cycle-back');

        $('#cycle-forward').click(function () {
            var $next = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.pars');
            if (!$next.length) $next = $pars.first();
            $next.addClass('active');
            if ($pars.last().is(':visible')) {
                $fwdBtn.disabled = true;
            } else {
                $fwdBtn.disabled = false;
                $backBtn.disabled = false;
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('#cycle-back').click(function () {
            var $prev = $pars.filter('.active').removeClass('active').prev('.pars');
            if (!$prev.length)
                $prev = $pars.last();
            $prev.addClass('active');
            if ($pars.first().is(':visible')) {
                $backBtn.disabled = true;
            } else {
                $backBtn.disabled = false;
                $fwdBtn.disabled = false;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem could be tackled in a more object-oriented way. How about creating an object that deals with an array of elements? That way you could delegate that stuff to it an avoid some if-elses.

```
// Constructor function in order to create objects that deal with collections of elements. Implements some simple collection's methods.
function ElementManager(elArray) {
    var size = elArray.length,
        currentIdx = 0;

    this.getCurrent = function() {
        return elArray[currentIdx];
    };

    this.next = function() {
        currentIdx = currentIdx < size - 1 ? (currentIdx + 1) : 0;
        return this;
    };

    this.previous = function() {
        currentIdx = currentIdx === 0 ? (size - 1) : (currentIdx - 1);
        return this;
    };

    this.first = function() {
        currentIdx = 0;
        return this;
    };

    this.last = function() {
        currentIdx = size - 1;
        return this;
    };

    this.isLast = function() {
        return currentIdx === size - 1;
    };

    this.isFirst = function() {
        return currentIdx === 0;
    };
}
```

As you can see, it's a very simple implementation of a Collection's interface that could find in many languages such as Java or C++.

Then, your code:

```
var elementManager = new ElementManager($('.pars')),
    $fwdBtn = $('#cycle-forward'),
    $backBtn = $('#cycle-back');

function moving(direction) {
    var $currentElement = $(elementManager.getCurrent()),
        $nextElement = $(elementManager[direction]().getCurrent());

    $currentElement.removeClass('active');// Remove active class of current element
    $nextElement.addClass('active');// Activate next element.
    $fwdBtn.prop('disabled', elementManager.isLast());// If it's last element, disable button, else activate it.
    $backBtn.prop('disabled', elementManager.isFirst());// If it's first element, disable button, else activate it.
}

// Add events.  
$fwdBtn.click(moving.bind(null, 'next'));
$backBtn.click(moving.bind(null, 'previous'));
```

In order to avoid code repetition, I used a couple of tricks (namely bind and accessing a property of the object using a variable), hope it doesn't complicate too much the code. As you can see, you have to disable/enable the buttons when you're in the last/first element (I think that was the bit that was wrong in your code). Hope it helps.

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x29qtwm6/).